# Why are transformers cores made of iron and not nickel, when the relative permeability is higher for nickel?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why are transformers cores made of iron and not nickel, when the relative permeability is higher for nickel?
The permeability of nickel being 600 and the one of iron being 200.

Comment: Cost ... and where does nickel saturate? Iron about 1.2T. Nickel about 0.5T from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_(magnetic)#:~:text=Seen%20in%20some%20magnetic%20materials,more%20or%20less%20levels%20off. That gives Iron the advantage.

Comment: Today, Iron is selling for $0.1235 / Kg.  Nickle is $15.602.     https://www.dailymetalprice.com/metalprices.php?c=fe&u=kg&d=1

Comment: I see, but the permeability is related to how much energy an inductor can store right? Is nickel better for an inductor?

Comment: @JakobFurbo - it depends on what you are trying to build. Indeed, a closed nickel core would have extremely high inductance, but it would store almost zero energy before it saturates. This is why Nickel is great for shielding low level magnetic fields. If you're making an inductor for energy storage, then you'll have to compromise the permeability of the system to prevent saturation anyway, so the low permeability of the core material is (largely) pointless.

Answer (score 7):

Transformer laminates are actually made from silicon steel and that raises the electrical resistance of iron to about 5 times greater hence, eddy current losses are much reduced by using silicon in the mix.

- For nickel the electrical conductivity is 1.43 x 10^7 and
- Iron is a bit higher resistance with electrical conductivity at 1.00 x 10^7.

Adding the silicon makes transformer laminate silicon steel about 7 times more resistive than nickel.

Magnetic saturation is also improved over nickel too: -

[image]

Magnetization curves of 9 ferromagnetic materials, showing saturation.

1. Sheet steel,
2. Silicon steel,
3. Cast steel,
4. Tungsten steel,
5. Magnet steel,
6. Cast iron,
7. Nickel,
8. Cobalt,
9. Magnetite

Compare (2) silicon steel with (7) nickel.

Graph courtesy of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_(magnetic)).

Comment: Wow, thanks. I think I misunderstood something then.

Answer (score 2):

To address your question specifically, the answer is that the increased permeability of Nickel is not that important in a power transformer.

The permeability of the material simply measures the preference for flux to flow through the core rather than leak through the air around the coils and bypass the core. The more flux that leaks, the less coupling between the coils and the efficiency of the transformer is reduced (the leaking flux appears as a parasitic inductance that requires reactive current to drive).

However, if we have, say 1 Wb of flux being produced by the primary coil, and the leakage path area is similar to the core area (a huge oversimplification, but probably not far off), then using an Iron core around 1/200Wb of the flux will leak. With a Nickel core this will reduce to 1/600Wb. But 0.5% isn’t much anyway and only contributes a small amount to electrical losses (from the extra reactive current required). If you are concerned about electrical losses they can easily be compensated for by increasing the wire size, which will be much cheaper than moving to Nickel (or more likely a 50/50 Nickel Iron alloy as has been noted in other answers, pure Nickel has a lower saturation flux density).

Interestingly, the main situation where increased permeability is useful, is in magnetic shielding, and this is where you will find Nickel alloys used a lot. In a shielding application you have a weak magnetic field and you want to reduce as much leakage as possible. In this application the 3x increase in permeability has a huge effect, as it means that much more of the stray flux will want to flow through the shield. In fact, it means the shield can be either 300% more effective for the same thickness, or made 30% of the thickness for the same effect. And with advanced alloys such as Mu-Metal we can do even better (at the expense of reducing the saturation flux further).

Essentially a 300% difference is worth is for shielding, but a ~0.3% difference is not worth it for a power transformer.

*Note: In the interest of not overcomplicating an already long answer, I have not addressed other factors in transformer design, such as the eddy current losses (as Andy Aka noted), or the effects of the lower saturation flux density. These all contribute to the reason we don't use Nickel, but your question was with regard to the difference in permeability.*